# Doctrine 1 : older than 1 year

Tags: doctrine

Can someone please tell me how to create a query to show something older than 1 year without using DATE_ADD because I guess this function is used just in doctrine2?

Answer (score 0):

Something like `Where (DateField > (GetDate() + 365))` should work.

Comment: What DB server are you using?